# `power/persist` file not found in USB device sysfs directory

Tags: 10.10, usb, kernel, usb-drive

The file [/usr/share/doc/linux-doc/usb/persist.txt.gz](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/usb/persist.txt) mentions that the USB-persist capability can be enabled for a given USB device by writing `1` to the file `persist` in that device's directory in `/sys/bus/usb/devices/$device/power`.  This is said — if I understood correctly — to allow mountings of volumes on the drive to persist across power loss during suspend.

However, I've discovered that the device I'd like to enable this facility for — a USB hard drive — does not have such a file in its corresponding directory, and that attempts to create it are rebuffed.

Is there perhaps a kernel module that needs to be loaded for this to work?  Do I need to build a custom kernel?  I'm running Ubuntu 10.10.

---

**UPDATE:**
Answer posted on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/79232/28489).

Comment: [cross-posted on Unix and Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5448/power-persist-file-not-found-in-usb-device-sysfs-directory)

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyway or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reason(s) why you want it open. Regards